# noClassDefFound error in native methods

Tags: java

I have this example class for using jline library:

```
[niko@localhost temporal]$ ls -l jline/example/Example.java
-rw-rw-r-- 1 niko niko 3502 Jul  6 00:20 jline/example/Example.java
[niko@localhost temporal]$ head -20 jline/example/Example.java
package jline.example;

import jline.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class Example {
    public static void usage() {
        System.out.println("Usage: java " + Example.class.getName()
                + " [none/simple/files/dictionary [trigger mask]]");
        System.out.println("  none - no completors");
        System.out.println("  simple - a simple completor that comples "
[niko@localhost temporal]$
```

when I run it I get this error:

```
[niko@localhost temporal]$ java -classpath ./:jline/example/:./jline-0.9.94.jar Example
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Example (wrong name:     jline/example/Example)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
[niko@localhost temporal]$
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke `java` with the fully qualified class name, which in your case is `jline.example.Example`. Additionally, your classpath should just be to the root of the package hierarchy, which is the current working directory by the looks of it.

```
java -classpath .:jline-0.9.94.jar jline.example.Example
```

This is just normal Java - I suggest you learn the basics of compiling and running Java programs before you get into third party libraries etc.